# Backup new entities in datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

How can I bulk download the datastore entities(each having a creation timestamp) that are created since the last download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it, the [Bulk Loader](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) does not offer any kind of incremental backup feature.